# Error 400 using REST APIs to IBM Watson IoT platform

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud, iot

I'm attempting to transmit a json formatted message using the REST APIs from an embedded system to the IBM Watson IoT Platform. I've tested the REST APIs using another program (postman) and it works fine however an identical string transmitted from my embedded system returns an error 400. Is there so "extra" security certificate I need in my embedded system to make this work? Or is there something else I am missing?

Here's a link to the REST API for messaging: https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/apis/swagger/v0002/http-messaging.html

The following is the string output from my embedded system (via socket connection) where typeID, deviceID, eventName, and orgID are correctly entered and encode64(name token) is the correct authorization string of the concatenation of the name and token encoded in base64.

```
POST /api/v0002/device/types/typeID/devices/deviceID/events/eventName HTTP/1.1
Host: orgID.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:80
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic encode64(name token)

{random JSON formatted message}
```

The socket connection is made by first resolving the IP address of the following URI: orgID.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com 
then employing standard socket connection function to the IP address and port 80.

While the IoT Platorm API make no mention of using port 80, I can transmit my JSON formatted message to my IoT Platform using port 80 through Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue. My ordering of the carriage return and new line characters was incorrect for the HTTP specification. That is: "\r\n" instead of "\n\r". Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Requests must include an authorization header. Basic authentication is the only method that is supported. Applications are authenticated by using API keys. When an application makes any request through the Watson IoT Platform HTTP REST API, username and password are required.

Refer to documentation:  https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/api.html#api

Comment: I am using the appropriate Authorization header. As I said, it works in postman but not on the embedded device (that is, if I was excluding the authorization in postman it would not work in postman).

Comment: Are you including a request header to specify Content-Type is   application/json ?

Comment: Valerie: Thanks for the responses: I've edited my post to provide a bit more information. To answer your question: Yes, I do specify the content-type as application/json